# Casting int to Object on java

Tags: java, casting

I have a question: I work in environment of Eclipse.

Sometimes the computer does not give to the following casting:

```
int a ... 
Object ans = (int) a;
```

But only this conversion:

```
int a ...
Object ans = (Integer) a;
```

I understand why you can do the casting between `Object` to `Integer`, but why primitive variable - there are times when you can, and there are times you can not do a casting?

Thank you

I am attaching the code which the compiler not let me make casting between `int` variable to  object:

```
/** @return minimum element */
    public Object minimum(){
        return minimum(this.root);
    }
    public Object minimum(BSTNode node){
        if (node.left != null) return minimum(node.left);
        return node.data;
    }
        /** @return maximum element */  
    public Object maximum(){
        return maximum(this.root);
    }
    public Object maximum(BSTNode node){
        if (node.right != null) return maximum(node.right);
        return node.data;
    }

    public Object findNearestSmall(Object elem) {
        int diff;
        diff = (int)maximum() - (int)minimum();
        if (compare(minimum(), elem) == 0) return elem;
        else return findNearestSmall(elem, this.root, diff);
    }   
    public Object findNearestSmall(Object elem, BSTNode node, int mindiff){
           if(node == null) return (int)elem - mindiff;

           int diff = (int)elem - (int)node.data;

           if(diff > 0 && mindiff > diff) mindiff = diff;
           /* Case 2 : Look for in left subtree */
           if(compare(node.data, elem)>-1)
                   return findNearestSmall(elem, node.left, mindiff);
           else
           /* Case 3 : Look for in right subtree */ 
                   return findNearestSmall(elem, node.right, mindiff);
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Before Java 1.5, you couldn't even do this:

```
int a;
...
Object x = (Integer) a;
```

The compiler would complain that `a` is of a primitive data type, and therefore cannot be cast to an object.

Starting with Java 1.5, Java introduced the concept of automatic *boxing*. So, the following became OK:

```
int a;
...
Object x = (Integer) a;
```

Because the compiler knows how to convert from a primitive `int` to the boxed type `Integer` automatically; and from `Integer` to an `Object` it's, well, not a problem.

However, what you're trying to do:

```
int a;
...
Object x = (int) a;
```

Is basically telling the compiler to *avoid* boxing. You explicitly tell the compiler to leave `a` as an `int`, and put a reference to that `int` into an `Object`. The compiler isn't designed to deal with such a case.

Comment: Autoboxing was introduced in 1.5

Comment: But What is interesting is that my friend has the same workspace(Not the same version), and in my friend's computer - the compiler does not complain (exactly the same code that I sent here)

Comment: @ZoharYosef what JDK does your friend use? what level?

Comment: @Isaac my JDK is 1.8.0. I have to ask my friend what he had. p.s. thank you very much, you have a Clear and good explanation

Comment: @ZoharYosef another thing to look out for is Eclipse settings. It's quite possible that your workspace is configured to give an error in such a case, and in your friend's workspace it's configured to forgive. Look at workspace -> preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings. Enjoy the Hummus in Tel Aviv. Shalom

Answer (score 3):

You cannot cast from a referenced data-type to a primitive data-type i.e. you cannot:

```
 Object x = (int)a;
```

You can however do:

```
 Object x = (Integer)a;
```

because `Integer` is a class and `int` is a primitive data-type.
If I assume it correctly, the functionality you want to achieve is get the integer's value from Object x which can be done as:

```
 Object x = (Integer)a;  
 //Do something and somewhere else  
 int z = ((Integer)x).intValue();
```

This may through a `ClassCastException` if it is not of `Integer` class.

Answer (score 0):

An `Integer` is also an `Object` and stays as an Object on the Heap.

An `int` is a *primitive type*. It is NOT an `Object`. An Object has its own state and behavioral properties, `int` doesn't have those. So you get a compilation error when trying to convert an Object to a primitive. On the other hand, Converting an int to Object is possible because of `Autoboxing`

Comment: _So you get a compilation error when trying to convert primitive to Object or vice-verse_ I wouldn't say this this is true. The compiler will autobox the conversion for you. The issue is with the cast to `int`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - My bad.. Changed the answer. Thanks.. :)

Comment: All primitives are auto(un)boxed to/from their wrapper classes. `int <-> Integer` is not a special case.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - Yes. But you cannot cast Objects to primitives. And converting primitives to Object(not their wrappers, int<->Object) directly is not good either.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the difference between *int* which is a primitive type, and *[Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html?is-external=true)*, which is a wrapper class in Java.

Answer (score 0):

But I am able to execute the following code. I am using jdk 1.6 and the following code is not throwing me any errors or runtime exceptions.

```
    int i=5;

    Object test = (int)i;

    System.out.println(test.getClass());
```

Output: class java.lang.Integer

Comment: Could someone help me understand how java handles this conversion internally.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry I am new here. yeah I have raised a seperate question.

Answer (score -1):

- **`int` is a primitive type.**
  Way of declaration: `int a = 5;`
- **`Integer` is a wrapper class** (it extends Object).
  Way of declaration: `Integer a = new Integer(5);`

---

When you write

```
Integer a = 5;
```

compiler automatically converts it to

```
Integer a = new Integer(5);
```

**This feature is called Autoboxing** *(since Java 5.0)*

---

- `int` can not be casted to `Object` as it is not a referenced data type (object) at all.
- But it can be casted to other primitive types.
- On the other hand, `Integer` can be casted to `Object`.

---

When you write

```
Object ans = (Integer) a;
```

compiler does autoboxing and then casts it.

```
Object ans = (int) a;
```

gives a compiler error because the cast to `int` is successful, but it can not be assigned to an `Object` reference.

Hope this helps.
Good luck.

Comment: This is an incorrect over-simplification of the issue. `new Integer` is not called and you should never declare an `Integer` with `new Integer`.

Comment: Integer class does use a facade of Integer objects behind the scene for -127 to 128. I think mentioning this would increase the complexity unnecessarily. Thank you for the feedback though.